# Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Project0_opengl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm writing right code but the compiler throws an error. The error says that the mistake is on `glGenBuffers` but I've copied it from the official website. Where is my mistake?

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    float pos[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    GLuint buf;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buf);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        printf("Error\n");

    printf("%s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I'm writing right code but the compiler throws an error" - Ehh, *no*. If the compiler generates an error then you are most likely *not* writing "correct code".

Comment: `int main(void)` is correct C, but in C++ the `void` is redundant.

Comment: `return -1;` - returning negative values from `main` is usually a mistake. It will not result in what you expect in most cases. Prefer returning `EXIT_FAILURE` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! It really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glewInit()` has to be called after the OpenGL context is made current, after [`glfwMakeContextCurrent`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga1c04dc242268f827290fe40aa1c91157).
But it has to be called before any OpenGL instruction. See also [Initializing GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html):

```cpp
// [...]

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    printf("Error\n");

float pos[6] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.0f,  0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f
};

GLuint buf;
glGenBuffers(1, &buf);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// [...]
```

Note, the instructions like `glGenBuffers` are function pointers. These pointers are initialized to `NULL`. `glewInit()` assigns the address of the function to those pointers.
When you try to call the function, before the initialization, this causes:

> Access violation executing location 0x00000000